# Order elements based on text inside them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple elements such as

```
<div class="state">
   <div class="second-column col-xs-5">
       <p class="subtitle-compliance">Date</p>
       <p class="data-retrieve">16 Apr 2020 02:06 PM CST</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="state">
   <div class="second-column col-xs-5">
       <p class="subtitle-compliance">Date</p>
       <p class="data-retrieve">17 Apr 2020 02:06 PM CST</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't know how many will I'll have at any time but I need to order them in the HTML.

I tried sorting them this way:

```
var divList = []
$('.state').each(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    divList.push(element);
});

divList.sort(function(a,b) {
    a1 = $(a).find('.second-column .data-retrieve').text()
    b1 = $(b).find('.second-column .data-retrieve').text()

    if(a1 > b1) return 1;
    if(a1 < b1) return -1;
    return 0;
});
```

And this seems to not do the trick for me right now.

Comment: Order by the date?

Comment: Yes exactly, the issue is that the elements that I get aren't sorted by date.

Comment: I've tried a couple times putting it exactly as the scenario you presented but it doesn't seem to work on my end :/

Comment: What are you trying exactly and what is it that doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `Date` object to convert to date from the date strings, then compare `Date.getTime()`:

```js
$("#sorted").html($('.state').clone().sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date($(a).find(".data-retrieve").text()).getTime() - new Date($(b).find(".data-retrieve").text()).getTime() > 0 ? 1 : -1;
}))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>Original:</b>
<div class="state">
  <div class="second-column col-xs-5">
    <p class="subtitle-compliance">Date</p>
    <p class="data-retrieve">16 Apr 2020 02:06 PM CST</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="state">
  <div class="second-column col-xs-5">
    <p class="subtitle-compliance">Date</p>
    <p class="data-retrieve">15 Apr 2020 02:06 PM CST</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="state">
  <div class="second-column col-xs-5">
    <p class="subtitle-compliance">Date</p>
    <p class="data-retrieve">11 Apr 2020 02:06 PM CST</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="state">
  <div class="second-column col-xs-5">
    <p class="subtitle-compliance">Date</p>
    <p class="data-retrieve">17 Apr 2020 02:06 PM CST</p>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
<b>Sorted:</b>
<div id="sorted"></div>
```